# Google visits on Statcounter. How?

Tags: googlebot, statcounter

In my website’s Statcounter report, I found page views from Google. I thought it may be a Google bot’s visit but I found that particular visit comes through a search query (`example.com+keyword`) and it also showing some other details like Browser, OS and Resolution. If it is Google bot then how did those details come from? Does is it Google bot or a human working on Google?

See this image:

[image: Google visits on statcounter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [verifying Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en). Looks like it could be a human visitor.

Googlebot identifies itself as [crawl..googlebot](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr:66.249.66.1).

Comment: Thank you dear.. I checked it and found that it could be a human visitor.. Helps a lot..